# Need help fast with my truck please

Tags: dodge, cel, o2-sensor, intermittent-problems, dakota

My 1994 dodge Dakota v8 starts fine and ildes fine. If I drive for about 10m my engine light comes on and my code for the 02 sensor goes off. My truck is straight piped and has no cat it has a steel pipe to replace it and goes all the way to the muffler.. One day I was driving down the highway and it wanted to bog and would cause a loud backfire sound. If I stopped the truck it would slowly die or even driving. I would have to floor it to keep it going. Could this be because of my 02 sensor??
And I have another code which is my IAC sensor that is going off. I need help badly

Comment: Welcome to the site. Neither the O2 nor the IAC is going to cause it to bog. The O2 you mention is the one for the cat, which in your truck has nothing to do with how it runs. It just checks the operation of the catalytic converter. If the code is for the front O2 sensor, it could possibly cause a running issue, but in most cases only causes someone to get worse and worse mileage as the sensor gets more "lazy". The IAC controls the idle. Since you say it idles fine, this leaves me to believe something else is going on. Clear the codes and see what comes back. Also, what is the exact O2 code?

Comment: I dont have a code finder I used the built in one on the truck it would be code 21 from the truck. I also got code 23 which is intake air temp sensor. Also code a got for my coolant not reading. It was driving perfect than all this Started and what got me was the major power loss and a very loud backfire shot.

Comment: You should probably do some checks first. fuel pressure, base timing, plug/wire condition etc... check your upstream o2s for fouling.

Comment: I just realized your 94 probably doesn't have a downstream O2 as it's not OBDII, but OBDI. If you don't have ***any*** O2 sensors, then it's a huge issue.

Comment: I have a O2 sensor by the headers but its more down the pipe so it would be before the cat. And the O2 sensor is putting off a light